# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string on line 8

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried checking many time , still gives me this error. Actually i am trying to create a php file with the contents of $output in it .

```
<?php 
include 'dbconfig.php';
$rand = $_GET['rand'];
$filename = $rand.".php";
$output = "<?php"; 
$output .="include '../dbconfig.php';";
$output .="$myself = basename(__FILE__, '.php'); ";
$output .="$query = mysqli_query($dbconfig,\"Select command from records where token = '$myself'\");";
$output .="if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)";
$output .="{";
$output .="while($row=$query->fetch_assoc())";
$output .="{";
$output .="$command = $row[command];";
$output .="}";
$output .="echo 'exec $command endexec';";
$output .="}";
$output .="?>";
$file = fopen("puppet\$filename","w");
fwrite($file,$putput);
$check = "Select * from records where usertoken = $rand";
$check1 = mysqli_query($dbconfig,$check);
if(mysqli_num_rows($check1)== 0){
$ins = "Insert into records (usertoken)Values('$rand')";
if(mysqli_query($dbconfig,$ins)){
$success=true;
}
}else{
$success=false;
}
?>
```

Comment: Php variables in your strings will be evaluated to their values because your strings are double-quoted, try single-quotes instead

Comment: This should be generating lots of errors into your error log even if they dont appear on your page **LOOK at your error log**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna go ahead a 'guess' that this is actually php trying to do the thing it does when it parses strings with double quotes. It will evaluate variables and stuff in the string when it runs.

Try single quoting the strings...

```
<?php 
    include 'dbconfig.php';
    $rand = $_GET['rand'];
    $filename = $rand.'.php';
    $output = '<?php'; 
    $output .='include \'../dbconfig.php\';';
    $output .='$myself = basename(__FILE__, \'.php\'); ';
    $output .='$query = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "Select command from records where token = \'$myself\'");';
    $output .='if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)';
    $output .='{';
    $output .='while($row=$query->fetch_assoc())';
    $output .='{';
    $output .='$command = $row[command];';
    $output .='}';
    $output .='echo \'exec $command endexec\';';
    $output .='}';
    $output .='?>';
    $file = fopen("puppet\$filename","w");
    fwrite($file,$output);
    $check = "Select * from records where usertoken = $rand";
    $check1 = mysqli_query($dbconfig,$check);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check1)== 0){
        $ins = "Insert into records (usertoken)Values('$rand')";
        if(mysqli_query($dbconfig,$ins)){
            $success=true;
        }
    }else{
        $success=false;
    }
?>
```

Comment: And it would help if you spelt vaiables correctly `fwrite($file,$putput);` I think OP means `fwrite($file,$output);`  `$putput != `$output`

Comment: If your `$putput` is broken you need to see a mechanic

Comment: @RiggsFolly lol... I really didn't read that far ahead. Just saw the quotes. Will update however because bored.

Comment: Sorry, should have read _And it would help if OP spelt ..._

Comment: @Michael still 'Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result on line 22'

Comment: @Akki if it is not a `mysqli_result` then it must be false and there is an issue with the request or the db connection.

Comment: Using $check1->num_rows it works